# Make a macro to copy a specific range of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, range

Since the "Copy" function under "Edit" in Google Sheets cannot be recorded when making a macro, I'm trying to write an App Script to do it.

In short I have a sheet called "Daily Log" and I want to copy the range of AA6:AH8 without needing to scroll back to the top, select the cells, copy, then scroll back down to where I am entering data.  As there can be 30+ unique entries per day after the reoccurring 3 that are in rows 6:8, this would save a lot of time.

Is it possible to copy a fixed range of cells with a macro so that I can then paste it wherever I want?

Thanks for the insights.

I tried using the "Record Macro" but it seems that Copy is not supported.

I did this successfully, but have no idea how to change set.Background('#ff000') to be copy the active range.

```
function Red() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AA6:AH8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('#ff0000');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Load Clipboard:

```
function loadClipBoard() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange("AA6:AH8").getDisplayValues();
  let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><body><textarea id="txt1" cols="40" rows="15"><?= vs ?></textarea><br><input type="button" value="Copy, Save & Close" onClick="doCopy();" /><script>function doCopy() {var element=document.getElementById("txt1");element.select();document.execCommand("copy");google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();}).delay();}</script></body></html>';
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplate(html);
  t.vs = vs.join('\n');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t.evaluate().setWidth(500).setHeight(400), "Dummy");
}

function delay() {
  return true;
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick once I changed the sheet name.  Much appreciated.  A lot more code than I expected :)